# Splitting a map into small grids based on coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, distance

I have an API that requires coordinates as rectangular search box. (x1,y1) is the upper left corner, and (x2,y2) is the lower right corner of the search box.

I am looking into a large area therefore have to split my area into smaller zones, namely grids. I wonder what is the best way to split my entire map into say, 1000 number of smaller grids and feed each smaller grid corresponding coordinates to the API. In other words, get, `$x_1_n$, $y_1_n$` and `$x_2_n$` and `$y_2_n$` where n is the grid id?

I am new in the field, but understand these calculations are on the basis of a spherical Earth. Can you provide any hint or even keywords that will get me into a right path and eventually write my script?

Comment: Could you please let us know which tools you are using?

Comment: @MyGIS - I am after a methodology - ideally I would like it in python or R !

Comment: Then have a look at Vincenty formula (in JavaScript): https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/354587

Comment: @user702846 I am not sure what kind of data you are using when you say map, so I assumed that was Shapefile format, please check out my response below

Comment: In fact it is country ! I think the shape files are out there, but not sure if the carry the actual coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

1. In R you can create a grid, please take a look at this documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mapplots/versions/1.5.1/topics/make.grid
2. Please take a look at this page, that might be what you need: (images taken form the same page, attributed to the author "Huanfa Chen")
   https://rpubs.com/huanfaChen/grid_from_polygon

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.